# Electric Light Bulb symbol (Unicode) output to terminalby C++

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, wchar-t, windows-terminal

I'm trying to output the symbol of Electric Light Bulb with code **U+1F4A1** to Windows Terminal (experiment with Unicode).  I can't realize how to do that. I tried to use **wchar_t**, **wcout**, to change console output code page, and with no result. Who made it. please tell how to do that.

```
#include <uchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
#include "Windows.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(12000);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(12000);

    /*Alternative*/
    system("chcp 65001");


    std::cout << u8"\u1F4A1" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the terminal font support the character you want to output, ie can you enter it just by typing it normally or pasting it from the clipboard?

Comment: Unless you are compiling with C++23, [Unicode Escape Sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) don’t work like that.

Comment: It can be normally pasting to code editor (using Visual Studio 2022). I tried to change terminal font but didn't find suitable yet. I wrote that new Windows Terminal had a lot of new features support